# Making python script results appear in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters

I have a model (ModelBuilder) and within I added a python script to calculate a field. My problem now is, that I don't know how to make the output appear in my model as it is the same as the input (only with the field calculated).

I imagine there is a very simple way, but I am new to ModelBuilder and python and just can't think of it?

Alternatively, I could also try using the field calculator, but I would prefer it this way.

And here is my script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)  # the workspace
inLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # The shapefile
inField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # The column in attr table with Area
outField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) # The column in attr table which should be calculated

# Create a list from area field and find min & max value

listing = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inLayer)
for row in rows:
    listing.append(row.getValue(inField))
del rows

listing.sort()
min = listing[0]
max = listing[-1]

# Calculate the normalized value

rows2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inLayer)
for row2 in rows2:
    row2.setValue(outField, (max - row2.getValue(inField))/(max - min))
    rows2.updateRow(row2)
del rows2
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [add your script as a tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000001r000000) in a custom Toolbox, then add your script tool into your ModelBuilder process.

When you create your script tool, be sure to [set the script tool parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) up so that you have the `Type` parameter set to "Derived" with the `Direction` parameter set to "Output".

Comment: Thanks for that answer. However, the problem is not fully solved. It seems to go in the right direction. However, I cannot use the Output as a new Input in modelbuilder - I guess because I have no output mentioned in my script. So my next question is how to change my script to make that work?

Comment: I found the missing piece:

Comment: Nothing had to be changed in the script. Only I had to set the Obtained from Parameter to Input. Then everything works as it should. 
So thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help, @oddpodm.  If this resulted in the info you need, please click the little "checkmark" next to my answer to close this question.  Thanks.